# Facebook Graph API how to retrieve comments and follows made to a FB questionObject

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I need to retrieve the comments and follows made to a FB question.  I can retrieve a question object by calling:

https://graph.facebook.com/[user-id]/questions or https://graph.facebook.com/[question-id]

Each returns the question object, but that only includes the basic information and questionOptions. It does not include comments and follows.

anyone know how to retrieve this information?

Comment: Sorry, but this is currently not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using GRAPH API, use the following to GET the questions posted with all comments and likes for the same.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/questions

Comment: the graph API does not return comments or likes for the questions.